# Select comments with highest average rating within radius

Tags: mysql, average

I'm trying to get subjects with the highest average rating within a radius by averaging the comment rating column.

I've tried something along the lines of:

```
select avg(`rating`) AS `avgrate` , subject.*,
, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(22.28639) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( subject.long ) - radians(114.1491) ) + sin( radians(22.28639) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) )
AS distance 
from `subject_review` 
JOIN `subject`
ON subject_review.subject_id = subject.id
group by `subject_id`
HAVING distance <= 100 
order by `avgrate` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

This SQL works fine, I just need to add the radius filter,

```
select avg(`rating`) AS `avgrate` ,subject_review.id , subject.*
from `subject_review` 
JOIN `subject`
ON subject_review.subject_id = subject.id
group by `subject_id`
order by `avgrate` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: ? So what's the problem?

Comment: You have an error in your syntax....

Comment: Ah, the crucial piece of missing information - so, a plethora of commas

Comment: Is Dan Neely the resident archaeologist?